# How to protect from executing excessively large searches?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, connection-string

I would like to limit all user searches by 65,000 rows. This change should be invisible to users but function as a back end protection from users executing excessively large searches through the user interface.
I have use the Hibernate 3.6, MySQL 5.x and JBoss 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
maxRows - The maximum number of rows to return (0, the default means return all rows).